# Visual Studio 2015: Can't create a new empty project c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

I recently got the new version of Visual Studio and I can't seem to find how to create an empty project for C++. The options seem to be only C# and Basic.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed C++ project templates?

Comment: Visual C++ is no longer installed by default, you need to select it during a custom install.

Comment: The one you should download is Visual Studio Community Edition: https://www.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Can I somehow add it without reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, you can, you should Modify

Comment: If you have Community Edition

Comment: The newest update of VS 2015 enterprise removed my C++ so I could not create new C++ projects! I modified and now it works again.. great!!

Answer (score 20):

The default (typical) installation of Visual Studio 2015 no longer contains the C++ compiler and tools. This was a very popular ask from the community as many developers do not want the footprint C++ brings.

If you go and try to uninstall Visual Studio 2015, the installer screen will pop up and you'll see a button named "Modify". This will change your current installation. Do a custom install and pick the C++ features / libraries that you require.

As far as I know, most editions have C++ support, including Express for Windows, Express for Desktop and the popular Community edition.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open VS with Admin's rights. I tried it, and it works!